# Put the onPressed function on the Container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I need take off FlatButton and put this function all the container, using onPressed of button function. I don't know if is possible... How I can do this?

```
Widget _buildFrontWidget() {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("CARD",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF2e282a),
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)
            ),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => _foldingCellKey?.currentState?.toggleFold(),
              child: Text(
                "Open",
              ),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.indigoAccent,
              splashColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget _buildInnerTopWidget() {
    return Container(
        color: Color(0xFFff9234),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text("TITLE",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFF2e282a),
                fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)));
  }

  Widget _buildInnerBottomWidget() {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFFecf2f9),
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => _foldingCellKey?.currentState?.toggleFold(),
          child: Text(
            "Close",
          ),
          textColor: Colors.white,
          color: Colors.indigoAccent,
          splashColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: you need GestureDetector

Comment: Tks Eugene, for your help... I've used it and I've got the positive result. I would like apply this function on the all region of FoldingCell (Container or Widget), but I still have not been able to.

Comment: if i understood correctly you can add `behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque` to gesture detector

Answer (score 0):

Wrap into a InkWell, like that

```
Widget _buildFrontWidget() {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: _foldingCellKey?.currentState?.toggleFold(),
    child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("CARD",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF2e282a),
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)),
          ],
        )),
  );
}
```

Comment: tks for your help, but there is a detected error at onTap code line.
I' something like that using 
I got a positive result using GestureDetector. No was what I would like, but I have to click on the letters.

Comment: Widget _buildFrontWidget() {return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => _foldingCellKey?.currentState?.toggleFold(),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("CARD",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF2e282a),
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }